# Smart way to combine collections based on a common property

Tags: java, guava

Say I have the following two classes...

```
public class Computer {
    private String computerName;
    private boolean hasTechnicalIssue;
}   

public class TechnicalIssue {
    private String issueId;
    private String computerName;
}   

public class ComputerManager {

   ComputerDao computerDao;
   IssueDao issueDao;

   public void getComputers {
       List<Computer> computers = computerDao.getComputers();
       List<TechnicalIssues> technicalIssues = issueDao.getTechnicalIssues();  
       // I would like to do something here to set the hasTechnicalIssue flag
   }

}
```

Both the Computer class and the TechnicalIssue class have a computername property.

Is there smart way using Guava that I can set the hasTechnicalIssue boolean in the computers list by using the computerName property in the list of TechnicalIssues?

For example if the list containing computers contains an entry with a computerName of computer9999 and the list containing Technical Issues also contains an entry with the same computerName, hasTechnicalIssue on the Computer class should equal true.

Comment: If you don't mind may I suggest you something? I think there is a design flaw here. Lets say you keep everything as is. And lets say I tell you a way to do what you want to do. But, there will be a problem when 2 or more entires inside List<TechnicalIssues> technicalIssues has same 'computerName' names.

Comment: No worries. Happy to take suggestions... that's fine if a computer has more than one technical issue. I just want to know if there is at least one that exists for that given computer. The SQL that is behind getTechnicalIssues does a distinct from the database on computer name.

Comment: U specifically asked for a solution that involves Guava. I have never used Guava. If you don't mind I can tell you how to do it in a simple way:  for (int i = 0; i < computers.size(); i++){
  String cn = computers.get(i).getComputerName();
  for (int j = 0; j < technicalIssues.size(); j++){
   if (cn.contentEquals(technicalIssues.get(j).getComputerName())){
   computers.get(i).gethasTechnicalIssue = true;
   break;
  }   
  }
  }

Comment: thanks for that. Yea I was hoping for something a bit more fancy using guava. But will have to resort to something like you did if nothing available.

Comment: Can I post that as an answer and could you accept it?

Comment: You could post it as an answer and I will up vote but was hoping for a nice guava way. So I will wait to see if anyone else has an alternate answer.

Comment: I posted it thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a O(n*m) algorithm (O(n^2) supposing the 2 collections have comparable sizes), you need to iterate on each collection once, and that's possible if you collect an intermediate collection, i.e. the names of computers involved in technical issues:

```
Set<String> computersWithIssues = Sets.newHashSetWithExpectedSize(technicalIssues.size());
for (TechnicalIssue issue : technicalIssues) {
    computersWithIssues.add(issue.getComputerName());
}
for (Computer computer : computers) {
    computer.setHasTechnicalIssue(computersWithIssues.contains(computer.getComputerName());
}
```

You could get all fancy with Guava and use a `Function<TechnicalIssue, String>` to transform the collection of technical issues into the collection of names, but unless you need to generalize for some reasons, it'll just be noise here. See the [caveat](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#caveats) in the explanation of functional concepts in Guava, the point being that it's not clearer or shorter when writing:

```
Function<TechnicalIssue, String> toName = new Function<>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(TechnicalIssue input) {
        return input.getComputerName();
    }
}
Set<String> computersWithIssues = FluentIterable.from(technicalIssues)
    .transform(toName)
    .toSet();
```

Comment: thanks. That's a nice way to avoid the O(n*m) algorithm. And thank you for the Guava alternative which I won't use but is nice to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an approach for a `FluentIterable` and the use of the `anyMatch` operator.  Key things to note:

- We don't care *where* the match occurs in the list of technical issues, so long as there *is* a match
- We need to iterate across all elements in the computers collection
- This is still an expensive operation in that we're broaching O(nm)

With that in mind, the fluent iterable expression is straightforward.

```
final FluentIterable<TechnicalIssue> fluentIterable = FluentIterable.from(technicalIssues);
for(Computer computer : computers) {
    boolean match = fluentIterable.anyMatch(new Predicate<TechnicalIssue>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final TechnicalIssue input) {
            return input.getComputerName().equals(computer.getComputerName());
        }
    });
    if(match) {
        computer.setHasTechnicalIssue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Computer {

private String computerName;
private boolean hasTechnicalIssue;

public String getComputerName() {
    return computerName;
}

public void setComputerName(String computerName) {
    this.computerName = computerName;
}

public boolean isHasTechnicalIssue() {
    return hasTechnicalIssue;
}

public void setHasTechnicalIssue(boolean hasTechnicalIssue) {
    this.hasTechnicalIssue = hasTechnicalIssue;
}
```

}

class TechnicalIssue {

```
private String issueId;
private String computerName;

public String getComputerName() {
    return computerName;
}

public void setComputerName(String computerName) {
    this.computerName = computerName;
}

public String getIssueId() {
    return issueId;
}

public void setIssueId(String issueId) {
    this.issueId = issueId;
}
```

}

class ComputerDao {

```
List<Computer> getComputers() {
    List<Computer> clist = new ArrayList<Computer>();
    Computer c = new Computer();
    c.setComputerName("rahul");
    c.setHasTechnicalIssue(true);
    clist.add(c);
    Computer c1 = new Computer();
    c1.setComputerName("rahul1");
    c1.setHasTechnicalIssue(false);
    clist.add(c1);
    return clist;
}
```

}

class IssueDao {

```
List<TechnicalIssue> getTechnicalIssues() {
    List<TechnicalIssue> clist = new ArrayList<TechnicalIssue>();
    TechnicalIssue c = new TechnicalIssue();
    c.setComputerName("rahul");
    c.setIssueId("111");
    clist.add(c);
    TechnicalIssue c1 = new TechnicalIssue();
    c1.setComputerName("rahul1");
    c1.setIssueId("112");
    clist.add(c1);
    return clist;
}
```

}

public class QuestionClass {

```
ComputerDao computerDao;
IssueDao issueDao;

public void getComputers() {
    computerDao = new ComputerDao();
    issueDao = new IssueDao();
    List<Computer> computers = computerDao.getComputers();
    List<TechnicalIssue> technicalIssues = issueDao.getTechnicalIssues();
    for (Iterator<TechnicalIssue> it = technicalIssues.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        TechnicalIssue technicalIssue = it.next();
        for (Iterator<Computer> it1 = computers.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
            Computer computers1 = it1.next();
            if (technicalIssue.getComputerName().equals(computers1.getComputerName()) && computers1.isHasTechnicalIssue()) {
                System.out.println("Has techincal issue : " + computers1.getComputerName());
                //Print all other details
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    QuestionClass QC = new QuestionClass();
    QC.getComputers();
}
```

}

## Output ##
Has techincal issue : rahul
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: My main issue with this answer:  you don't actually *explain* any of it.  You just provide a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

U specifically asked for a solution that involves Guava. I have never used Guava. If you don't mind I can tell you how to do it in a simple way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < computers.size(); i++){ 
String cn = computers.get(i).getComputerName(); 
for (int j = 0; j < technicalIssues.size(); j++){ 
if (cn.contentEquals(technicalIssues.get(j).getComputerName())){ 
computers.get(i).setHasTechnicalIssue(true); 
break; 
} 
} 
}
```